# If a = str(integer), do print(len(a)) and return len(a) work the same in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to programming and have just briefly learned functions in python. I do not understand why `print(len(str))` don't work the same as `return len(str)` in a function.

I have tried both print and return for the last statement of the function and am confused about my understanding of `len()`. I need some guidance, thank you! Perhaps someone can guide me as to how I can further improve my foundation as I am still pretty new to programming. Thank you!!

```
def numDigits(n):
    #return number of digits in an integer
    str_digits = str(n)
    print(len(str_digits))

numDigits(833)
```

If I change the

`print` to `return len(str_digits)` and

`numDigits(833)` to `print(numDigits(833))`,

I get my expected answer.

What i expected:

```
3
```

Actual result:

```
3
None
1
2
4
3
```

Comment: It looks like you’re getting the `None` that functions return by default, but I don’t understand how you got the rest of that output.

Comment: @DavisHerring: Yeah, I can't reproduce. The `None` output might occur in a custom REPL that was stringifying the return value of `numDigits` unconditionally (most interpreters suppress echoing for `None`, but it's not required), but the rest is nonsense, and couldn't be produced from the provided code.

Comment: Perhaps it is because I am using an online python interpreter as I am using "how to think like a computer scientist". Thank you both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case `numDigits` doesn't `return` a value from the function, and you only print it inside the function

```
def numDigits(n):
    #return number of digits in an integer
    str_digits = str(n)
    print(len(str_digits))

print(numDigits(833))
```

The output here is

```
3
None
```

The `3` comes from `print` and `None` comes from the function, and when you `print` it, it prints `None`

If you want to return, you need a return statement like `return len(str_digits)` at the end of the function like so

```
def numDigits(n):
    #return number of digits in an integer
    str_digits = str(n)
    print(len(str_digits))

    #Return statement
    return len(str_digits)

print(numDigits(833))
```

The output will now be

```
3
3
```

Now the first `3` comes from `print`, and the second 3 comes when you print what `numDigits` return, which is `3`